# What is this part used for on a 4g92/93 engine

Tags: electrical, part-identification, mitsubishi, lancer

I have problems with a Mitsubishi Lancer that uses a 4g92 engine (basicaly the same as a 4g93) in the troubleshooting process, I've found that if I move the part in the image, the car becomes unstable, I need to know what it is used for, so I can find a way to fix it properly o replace it.
It is attach with a bolt to the camshaft sensor holder, a wire comes out of the part and it is a bit chew up. [image]

Comment: What year is your Lancer? This looks to be a capacitor of some kind.